# Apply hover to multi level childrens of parent class

Tags: css, reactjs, hover

I am applying hover effect to parent class and its multi levels child classes using global css.
my code is

```
<div className="parentCard" id="#parentCard">
    <div className="child1Card" id = "#child1Card">
        <div className="c11">
            <h2 className="cardTitle"> its Challenge</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="c12">
            <IoIosLogIn className="iconStyle" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="child2Card" id = "#child2Card">
        <p className="cardContent"> contentnaskjndfv anfvoiernvweov on owiervni</p>
    </div>    
</div>
```

I am applying css to above div is as

```
.parentCard:hover{
    background:linear-gradient(to right, #ff6f00, #ff9100);
    color:#ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
```

above code is not working on 'c11' child class.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code, Thank you

Comment: what is the `className` ?? if you using plain `HTML`, use `class`

Comment: I am using react js thats why className is there.

Comment: are you using sass

Comment: no i am not using sass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just base only on what I understand to your question, maybe add same style on c11 class while you hover on the parent class. Please check code below:

```css
.parentCard:hover,
.parentCard:hover .c11 {
  background:linear-gradient(to right, #ff6f00, #ff9100);
  color:#ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: @MahiGunjal - glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

You have mistaked to write classname instead of class. I changed class from className in html. You can check it if you agree. Thanks

```css
.parentCard {-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;}
.parentCard:hover{background:linear-gradient(to right, #ff6f00, #ff9100);color:#ffffff;cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<div class="parentCard" id="#parentCard">
   <div class="child1Card" id = "#child1Card">
   <div class="c11">
       <h2 class="cardTitle"> its Challenge</h2>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="child2Card" id = "#child2Card">
      <p class="cardContent"> contentnaskjndfv anfvoiernvweov on owiervni</p>
   </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure of this. OP is likely using React.

Comment: I am using react js not a plain html.

Comment: oh, I understand and didn't know to react js. Thanks